# Ajax call onclick happens only once

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, onclick, submit

I have a from in my page which I want to submit, and I using an ajax call:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#password_change").click(function() {                    
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'set_password.php',
            data: 'password=' + $('#password').val(),
            success: function(data) {
                var obj = JSON.parse(data);              
                if(obj.success == '1') {    
                    $('#message').show();                            
                }else{
                    $('#fail_message').show();                            
                }
            }
        });
    });
 });
```

And my form:

```
<form id="password_form" name="password_form" action="" method="POST" style="">
    <input type="password"  class="required" id="password" value="" />
</form>
```

The first time I click the submit button, I get the right message and everything seems to work fine. Then I click again the submit button for second time, but then the data that I am sending through the ajax call are empty, so I am getting a wrong reply for the ajax call.

Does anyone have an idea why could this happen?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you inspecting the network traffic with e.g. dev console in Chrome? Is the ajax request being sent with an empty data payload? Using just your code in a jsfiddle works fine (the request can be sent with the password data many times) so it should be something else - your PHP perhaps, or some other JavaScript on your page.

Comment: Can you check $('#password').val() value after second click , before the ajax call.

Comment: I would recommend that you remove the entire `$.ajax` call and just do an `alert($('#password').val())` on the click event, to make sure that it's not something in the client JavaScript code. If the alert doesn't fire more than once then you know it's a JavaScript issue at least.

Comment: well I did that, and it seems that the values is still there and it is right. also I cheche the post values in firebug and look good. If I am printing them however in my php file they look empty. so probably something is wrong in the php?

Comment: Ok I found it is was a problem in my php file, you are right.

Answer (score 0):

I think when button click, it also post backed. You stop trigger post back using [event.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) after onclick. try modify code:

```
...
$("#password_change").click(function(e) {  
   e.preventDefault();
   $.ajax({
     ...
     ...
   });
});
...
```

Comment: Check my update. I have add e parameter on .click(function(e) {... that miss before.

Comment: Is your page being reloaded (does it "blink"?) when you click the submit button? Does the password field turn empty after the first click or are the charaacters still there?

Comment: @novellino demo for `preventDefault`: [jsfiddle.net/XBv4K/](http://jsfiddle.net/XBv4K/)